# Unrecognized Selector sent to Instance Firebase auth

Tags: swift, firebase, button, click

Setting up firebase auth and the app keeps crashing once the Sign Up button is tapped, I have the button linked to @IBAction for firebase signup and all classes are correct for each view controller (login and signup), I also have the correct @IBOutlets for the text fields.

```
2019-03-03 18:50:06.225729+0000 Spring[40363:3684981] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[Spring.registerView loginViewControllerButton:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7f7f39407ec0'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone else experiencing this issue, I resolved it by checking for any extra outlets on my UIButton where I had two that weren't necessary, removing these solved the issue for me.

After googling I found this page helped with my issue:
[Solution](https://teamtreehouse.com/community/swift-unrecognized-selector-sent-to-instance)